# Netsuite : EntitySearchBasic Tutorial/Sample

Tags: netsuite

We are working on C#.Net4.0 desktop application where user enters Netsuite CRM credentials and hits the login button.We are able to validate the user login details using passport authentication.Is there any way or api available where we can retrieve the list of objects (contact, customer etc) from the Netsuite CRM after successful login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a search in order to get these Customer, Contact , etc.
Here is a sample code for **Customer Search**

```
            CustomerSearch custSearch = new CustomerSearch();
            CustomerSearchBasic custSearchBasic = new CustomerSearchBasic();
            SearchStringField entityId = null;
            if (!customerEmailId.Equals(""))
            {
                entityId = new SearchStringField();
                entityId.@operator = SearchStringFieldOperator.contains;
                entityId.operatorSpecified = true;
                entityId.searchValue = "abc";
                custSearchBasic.email = entityId;
            }                
            custSearch.basic = custSearchBasic;

            SearchPreferences preferences = new SearchPreferences();
            preferences.bodyFieldsOnly = false;
            NetsuiteSession.session.searchPreferences = preferences;

            SearchResult result = NetsuiteSession.session.search(custSearch);
```

Similarly you can use searches for contact and other records that you want.

Answer (score 0):

For getting Customers use CustomerSearchBasic

http://tellsaqib.github.io/NSPHP-Doc/dd/d21/class_customer_search_basic.html

Similarly for Contacts use ContactSearchBasic

http://tellsaqib.github.io/NSPHP-Doc/dc/d48/class_contact_search_basic.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [SuiteTalk Schema Browser](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/SchemaBrowser/indexv2013_1_0.html) .

In Schema browser you can find the complete definition of NetSuite API.

The UI is not that pretty but you will find all the possible API things there.

For example to find contact or customer search locate Relationship.xsd under records and expand it.